# Get all ordered products for all customers

Tags: magento-1.7, product, orders, customer

I am using Magento 1.7. I want to get all the products that each one of the customers bought in the past.

**Edit**: I need the list of products because I am trying to design and implement a recommender system, and I need the products that the users bought in the past to try to use it as the data that will feed my system.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you need this via a single query, or it can be split on multiple queries? you need it for a report, for something custom? Please describe the scenario you have.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$col = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();

foreach($col as $item)
  echo $item->getOrder()->getCustomerName().' bought '. $item->getProduct()->getSku()."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I tried the code and it's not working. I created a file in the root directory, added the line `require_once('app/Mage.php');` but got an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on null.`

Comment: please see the updated code. Just copy paste.

Comment: Thank you; this time I get a memory error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2098200576 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73 bytes)`. But I don't understand, 73 it's less than this memory size indicated...

Comment: please include ini_set('memory_limit','2048M'); after Mage::app()

Comment: you are very welcome!